# replace words in mysql

Tags: mysql, replace, updates

i want to replace some words from a text string using PHP & MySQL.

for e.g. -

the text column in the database contains the value "Word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word3".

i want to replace "word3" and "word4" with "newword". The challenge is not to replace the last word which is also "word3"

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: suggestion is learn about string functions like `str_replace()`

Comment: Replace in the database or the output?

Comment: @JohnConde - i did study up on the srt_replace function and as per my understanding it does not have the capability of specifying the startword and lastword between which you would want to update your string

Comment: @hjpotter92 - i am trying to replace the string and ultimately store it in the database. if this can be done directly in the database also it would be fine i guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard chars and control symbols in order to replace %word%, or %wo.d% the same way you can stop replacing if certain count of symbols is reached

Comment: Also, if you want to replace smth like 'word1, word2, word3, word4, word3' you can `UPDATE table SET col = 'word,1 word2, wordX, word4, word3' where col = 'word1, word2, word3, word4, word3'` but I don't see it to be universal method of doing something, LIKE search also won't help that much

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
UPDATE `tableName`
SET `field` = REPLACE( ' word3 ', ' newword ', REPLACE(' word4 ', ' newword ', `field`) );
```

---

Notice the extra spaces before and after `word3` and `word4`.

---

Based on comments:

```
UPDATE `tableName`
SET `field` = TRIM( REPLACE(' word3 word4 ', ' newword ', CONCAT( ' ', `field` )) );
```

Comment: hey thanks. i want to actually replace word3 and word4 with a single newword. also from the above statement, won't both the instances of word3 get replaced?

Comment: But it will not handle the last word. see in post "The challenge is not to replace the last word which is also "word3""

Comment: It will handle the last word because of the trailing spaces in the `REPLACE` arguments. But I don't think it'll handle cases where `word3` or `word4` are the *first* word. Perhaps change `field` to `CONCAT(' ', field)`?

Comment: @user2131970 Edited reply.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi I think that is what it was doing.

Comment: @EdGibbs Thanks for the tip about `CONCAT` =)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this php script to replace "word3" and "word4" to "newword".

<?php

$arr = array("word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word3","word4");

print_r(str_replace("word3","newword",$arr,$i));

print_r(str_replace("word4","newword",$arr,$i));

echo "Replacements: $i";
?>

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
<?php
$mystr = "Word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word3";
$mywords = explode(' ', $mystr);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mywords)-1; $i++) {
  if ($mywords[$i] == 'word3' || $mywords[$i] == 'word4') {
    $mywords[$i] = 'newword';
  }
}
$newstr = implode(' ', $mywords);
print("newstr = $newstr");
?>
```

This splits the words into an array, replaces all `word3` and `word4` with `newword` *except* for the last element of the array, then joins the words back into a string. The output was as expected:

```
Word1 word2 newword newword word5 word3
```